# Access pane settings from a view

Tags: 7, views, hooks, panels

Is there a way to access pane settings from the view pre build hook? I have a view being rendered inside a content pane. I have altered the pane's settings form and added a setting field. Now I need to access this field in the `hook_views_pre_build` in order to change something in the view. Is there a way for me to access that value?

Comment: Just commenting to let you know there are "allow" settings in the view content pane settings that allow some pane settings to be changed. Maybe you're looking for something more complex but it's a kind of hidden feature.

Comment: I know about this, but it isn't exactly what I was looking for. I need a custom setting in the view pane. I created the field and I store it in the view pane configuration, but for some reasons my "pane_conf" array doesn't have my setting in $view object which come to pre_build hook